# Python 'with' implementation

Tags: python, with-statement

In an interview they asked me about Python **with** keyword implementation. I could not answer except its use in `open`ing files and in `lock`. Then they asked me why don't we close file in `with open("x.txt") as f:`

Can anyone tell about `with` implementation and how does it behave differently for files and locks?